# File sources of classes present in two libraries in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using Gradle on IntelliJ and I have a peculiar issue with my dependencies: two of them contain a few of the same classes (apart from other files from each library), but one comes with the sources and the other one doesn't. The result is IntelliJ gives preference over to the one that doesn't contain the sources and I have to attach them manually (which is bad, because they'll be gone on every Gradle sync).

How can I choose the order of preference? And yes, I need both dependencies, even with their issues, but I also need the sources of the common files.

Comment: Not an expert on IntelliJ, but have you tried updating the order of  modules and libraries? That might fix it.

Comment: `How can I choose the order of preference?` IDE uses the order of dependencies in [dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#sort-dependencies) of the module. This order should be the same as declared order in gradle build script.